# Paypal integration for Phonegap 2.9.0

Tags: cordova, paypal, phonegap-plugins

i am trying to implement paypal for phonegap 2.9.0.No suitable plugins for it.I can't see manual implementation procedure for phonegap.How to implement Paypal in phonegap 2.9.0

Answer (score 0):

You are probably aware of official paypal plugin here: https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Cordova-Plugin

I can only suggest to try it. If it's not working for you, at lease it's open source. You can try debugging and fixing, or just look at the source code and implement your own plugin.

I used the plugin for a cordova 3.6 project successfully, it's pretty well written.

Comment: i am working with this plugin only.i am getting error class not found error.while running this line. cordova.exec(null, failureCallback, "PayPalMobile", "setEnvironment", [environment]);

Comment: Sounds like your Eclipse side of code does not have the java files added, or js cannot find it. It's really hard to comment for 2.9 though. Sorry..

Comment: Any body have used paypal integration in phonegap 2.9.0.Does exact manual integration procedure is available for Phonegap 2.9.0